# How to dynamic add model to viewport when animation completed in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, 3d, storyboard

I am using `StoryBoard` to do animation in WPF and I use multiple `DoubleAnimation` in that `StoryBoard`. And I want to add some model when that `DoubleAnimation` is completed. I tried to use `DoubleAnimation.Completed` event but it only fired when the whole `StoryBoard` completed. How can I achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't yet, add to your view's code-behind:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
```

Then add (assuming your `Viewport3D` is named "mainViewport":

```
void AddModel(GeometryModel3D mod)
{
    mainViewport.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D() { Content = mod });
}
```

And call when you want to add a model.

Comment: Hi newb, I know about mainViewport.Children.Add; but my problem here is that: storyBoard is running and I want to call that function when it reaches specific time.

Comment: Have you explored using a `System.Timers.Timer` that starts at the same time as your Storyboard then does a callback to add the appropriate model when its `Interval` elapses?

Comment: Sorry newb but I have to changed my question a bit, because but Interval and StoryBoard.CurrentTimeInvalidated did not give me the correct time as I calculated so I have to change my method.

Comment: Are you using the same `DoubleAnimation` for multiple animations? That might be why it waits until the end of the storyboard to fire the event. You might try creating multiple DoubleAnimations.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing, I create multiple DoubleAnimation like this:    var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
                animation.Completed += new EventHandler(animation_Completed);   but As you can see, each is a new instance of DoubleAnimation and I add them to StoryBoard but the animation_Completed even fire all at once when the storyboard finish.